# Error reading csv file to dataframe in dask and pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dask

I am trying to read a csv file using dask(also pandas) but im getting the below error.i tried changing the encoding formats but nothing seems working. but when i do save as csv `ut8` in excel the code starts working. same i tried with pandas and gives me same error.i tried explicitly giving the encoding as `utf-16` but it got error saying asking to use `utf-16-le or utf-16-be`. when i used also i got the errors. 
Is there something wrong with the csv file that I am using?

```
import dask.dataframe as dd


with open(Mar_N_W, 'rb') as f: 
    result = chardet.detect(f.read()) 
    Mar_NW = dd.read_csv(Mar_N_W,encoding=result['encoding'],sep=None)


~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py in _next_iter_line(self, row_num)
   2693 
   2694         try:
-> 2695             return next(self.data)
   2696         except csv.Error as e:
   2697             if self.warn_bad_lines or self.error_bad_lines:

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    320         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    321         data = self.buffer + input
--> 322         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    323         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    324         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\encodings\utf_16.py in _buffer_decode(self, input, errors, final)
     67                 raise UnicodeError("UTF-16 stream does not start with BOM")
     68             return (output, consumed)
---> 69         return self.decoder(input, self.errors, final)
     70 
     71     def reset(self):

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode byte 0x0a in position 0: truncated data
```

Comment: what is `Mar_N_W` variable used for ?

Comment: I edited your question. Please try to avoid the use of non-standard alias.

Comment: Mar_N_W is the file name of csv file. that valriable contains the path of the file.